# Why does RDD.getStorageLevel.useMemory return true, but Spark UI storage not displaying cached data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd

I am learning Apache Spark and working with the RDD and cache RDD processes.

I got to know that We can check if a RDD is cached or not using rdd.getStorageLevel.useMemory command in scala terminal.

So here is the commands which i followed:

```
scala> years.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res12: Boolean = false

scala> years.cache();
res13: years.type = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at <console>:29

scala> years.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res14: Boolean = true
```

So that means the years rdd now got cached.

But when i checked the spark UI storage tab, i could find nothing.
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Is there anything missing? If the command line show it has been cached (as it is returning true), then why does it not showing on the UI?

Comment: It won't get cached until is computed atleast once. call an action. Use `years.first` and then check the Storage tab.

Comment: But the years.getStorageLevel.useMemory command returns true. Isn't that specify it is cached?

Comment: It does specify that it is cached but you won't actually see it in cache unless you call an action. It's like when you use `sc.textFile` you do get an RDD to work with, but it's not materialized unless there's an action involved. Lazy Evaluation FTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `years.cache()` just marks `years` RDD to be cached the next time an action is executed.

[RDD.cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@cache():RDD.this.type) uses `MEMORY_ONLY` storage level.

> **cache(): RDD.this.type** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY).

That gives you the answer why you get `true` when executing the following code:

scala> years.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res14: Boolean = true

It simply "queries" the attributes of `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level **and** does not tell you whether `years` was indeed cached already or is about to be.

---

I think that you'd have to go very deep to know whether a dataset has already been cached or not.

I think the simplest solution would be to use `SparkListener` API and intercept [SparkListenerBlockUpdated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBlockUpdated), but haven't done it before.

---

The following is about Dataset API that may or may be relevant (I was mistaken answering the question with Dataset API in mind).

[Dataset.cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@cache():Dataset.this.type) uses memory and disk when needed since it uses [StorageLevel.DISK_AND_MEMORY](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel$@MEMORY_AND_DISK:org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel) storage level.

> **cache(): Dataset.this.type** Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).

That gives you the answer why you get `true` when executing the following code:

```
scala> years.getStorageLevel.useMemory
res14: Boolean = true
```

It simply "queries" the attributes of `MEMORY_AND_DISK` storage level **and** does not tell you whether `years` was indeed cached already or is about to be.

---

In order to check if a dataset has already been *marked to be* cached, you can use `CacheManager` (that is shared across `SparkSessions` through `SharedState` and available as `spark.sharedState.cacheManager`).

It is an internal API so use with caution.

```
val cached = spark.range(5).cache
scala> spark.sharedState.cacheManager.lookupCachedData(cached.queryExecution.logical)
res20: Option[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CachedData] =
Some(CachedData(Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=Some(8))
,InMemoryRelation [id#331L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   +- *Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
))
```

As a matter of fact, `CacheManager` will warn you if you try to cache the same (logical plan of) Dataset twice.

```
scala> val cached = spark.range(5).cache
17/12/07 15:00:34 WARN CacheManager: Asked to cache already cached data.
cached: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
```